# How to define precisely the radius size when using 'select features by radius' in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features

I'd like to select features with circles having precise radius in QGIS.
By default this tool is freehand so it is hard to get a precise value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if there's a direct approach to this but there are alternative methods:

- ### Fast, less precise

Use the **Measure Line** tool from the toolbar to draw a radius as precise as you can (*remember to right-click to stop drawing the line*):

[image: Measure Line]

[image: Drew line]

Then use the **Select Features by Radius** tool to draw the circle from each point of the measured line:

[image: Select features by radius]

---

- ### Slow, more precise

Create a point layer and add a point. Use the **Buffer** tool (*Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer(s)* to create a polygon of the point (*maximise the "Segments to approximate" and set your buffer distance to what you want the radius to be, becareful as this is dependent on your CRS*).

Then use one of the **Select by location** tools (either from the *Processing Toolbox* or from *Vector > Research Tools > Select by location*), select both layers and check the *intersect* option:

[image: Select with buffer]

Comment: Thanks a lot. My 'Select by location' window is different from yours in 2.8.4 and 2.12.1. Which QGIS version do you use?

Comment: @NicolasBoisteault - Most welcome buddy! I used QGIS 2.12.0-Lyon for Windows. The **Select by location** window is from the _Processing Toolbox_, not from the toolbar menu. Perhaps that is the reason?

Comment: That's it! I read your answer too quickly and didn't notice there are two ways to **select by location**. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Updated answer to this question

There is now a new plugin called "*Select by radius plus*" tool which can be downloaded from the plugins menu in QGIS.

The user interface is as follows:

[image]

The user can select from either meters, kilometers or miles and also has the option to use centroid as the selection parameter.

The plugin was created by Lutra Consulting https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/, 
and the code repository can be found here:
https://github.com/lutraconsulting/qgis-select-by-radius-plus-plugin

Comment: not available in QGIS 3.x

Comment: It is but perhaps not in the plugin repository. It will need to be downloaded from Github

Answer (score 0):

The selection by radius should come in meters as default.